# Restrict access to WooCommerce products by country

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need Restrict access to WooCommerce products by country  and use this code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_is_visible', 'bbloomer_hide_product_if_country', 9999, 2 );
 
function bbloomer_hide_product_if_country( $visible, $product_id ){
   $location = WC_Geolocation::geolocate_ip();
   $country = $location['country'];
   if ( $country === "US" ) {
      $visible = false;
   }
   else { 
      $visible = true;
   }
   return $visible;
}
```

but have a problem And that is Google can not index this product.
How can I exclude Google bot?
please help to me

Comment: Hey, you could have put the link to the source where you got the snippet from :) In regard to your question, you can't do that, you either index it or noindex it, can't do it "by country"

Comment: You could try detecting user agent.